# client unable to recognizing cors enabled in web-api

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have tried to enable to cors in my webapi application, but I keep getting the following message. 
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://apitesting.domain1.com/api/stw?{}. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

The api/stw{}, returns a 200 response, when I call it from my client side(via local host), however I am unable to see any data in my console window of my browser debugging tool.

I have enabled the cors in the following files of my webapi:

**webconfig file**

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
<customHeaders>
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
</customHeaders>
```

**webAPI config class**

```
   public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

**STW API controller:**

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class STWController : ApiController
{
    private ### db = new ####();

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Loan> getData()
    {
      // get data
    }
}
```

I am using ajax method on the client side to call my server data from:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
       // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "http://apitesting.domain1.com/api/stw",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
             alert(data.toSource());
            console.log(data);

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $("#tbDetails").append("<tr><td>" + data[i].Name + "</td><td>" + data[i].loan + "</td><td>" + data[i].evnt + "</td></tr>");
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
});
```

In the network tab of my browser tool, i get the following request and response header:

**Response header:**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, *
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 321
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 14 Apr 2015 11:04:00 GMT
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By-Plesk: PleskWin
```

**Request Header:**

```
Host: apitesting.domain1.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101     Firefox/37.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:5472/cors.aspx
Origin: http://localhost:5472
Connection: keep-alive
```

Is there something I am missing from web api code, which is causing a conflict in the response and request headers. Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: Is WebDav installed on the server? You might need to add this to your web.config
<system.webServer>
 <modules>
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
 </modules>
</system.webServer>

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I can find out, if my server has `WebDav`. if I do not have WebDav, am I still required to add the above line to my web.config file.

Comment: No, you only need to remove it if it is there :). I uninstalled it completely on my server when I had this problem, but I don't know that uninstalling it is necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I can confirm, I do not have webdav installed on my server.  if you could provide further advice, as to how can I get my client code to read the data from hosting server, it would very much appreciated. thanks